# Syntax Error in bash while loop

Tags: bash

What is the error in that?

```
j=0
filenames=("")
filedates=("")

while read line
do
filenames[$j]="$line"
filedates[$j]=$(stat -c %y ${filenames[$j]} | cut -d ' ' -f1)
(( j++ ))
done < <(ls -t *.gz)
```

Out:

```
script.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
script.sh: line 9: `done < <(ls -t *.gz)'
```

Really i don't know the error in that while loop, i tested it on several machine but same problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `bash` specific `<(process substition)`, but running your script with `/bin/sh`.

Use `bash script.sh` instead of `sh script.sh`, and make sure the shebang uses bash and not sh.

Answer (score 1):

use a `for loop`

```
for file in *t.gz
do
   ...
done
```

Comment: am still dummy in bash, can u please right the whole loop for me?

Comment: @user3178889 That would be a completely different thing altogether, and cause you to miss out on a valuable learning opportunity. We were all dummies once.